# An endomorphism $f$ of a vector space is nilpotent; show that $\mathit{Id} - f$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, nilpotence

> An endomorphism $f$ of a vector space is nilpotent; show that $\mathit{Id} - f$ is invertible and give how is it written.

I’ve found this method:

$\mathit{Id} - f^n = \mathit{Id} = (\mathit{Id} - f)(Id + f + \dots + f^{n-1})$

but I'm looking for something more intuitive.

Comment: You've been on MSE for a while and you still didn't learn MathJax? Can you please spend just a few minutes and learn [how to format your equations](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Thanks.

Comment: i will be more cautious next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a pretty good intuition.

Since $f$ is nilpotent, there is an $n$ such that $f^n=0$, hence $\ \mathrm{Id}+f+f^2+\dots+f^{n-1}\ $ will be the inverse of $\ \mathrm{Id}-f\ $ by your formula.

Comment: so you can't see another way of imagining things?

Comment: Well, if you prefer, for finite dimension we can consider a basis where the matrix of $f$ is of Jordan normal form. Since $f$ is nilpotent, the only eigenvalue is $0$, so the matrix has all $0$ in the diagonal, and is an upper or lower triangle, so the matrix of $\mathrm{Id}-f$ will be definitely invertible.